# Using javascript to manipulate string into dom elements

Tags: javascript, replace, split

I have a string of text that is populated dynaimcally. In every string, there is one common word : "type". Given a string stored as a variable, I would like to use javascript to find the word "type" and place a dive before it, and then a closing div after the string. 
Like so:

```
var string = "Here is some text that contains the word type and more text after";
```

I would like the end result to be like so:

```
Here is some text that contains the word <div>type and more text after</div>
```

How can I go about this?

Current Code is below:

```
var wod = $("#wod a").attr("title");
    var newwod = wod.replace("Copyright 2012, GB Blanchard - Learn Spanish: www.braser.com","");
    //get ride of example and everythign after it
    var finalwod = newwod.split("Example")[0];
    var newstring = finalwod.replace(/(type.+)/,"<div>$1</div>");


   $("#wod span").append(newstring);
```

Comment: I would start by writing some code.  When it doesn't work, come back here and show us what you have.

Comment: What if there are more occurrences of "type"?

Comment: then we want to grab the first string "type"

Answer (score 4):

Just use `replace`:

```
string = string.replace(/(type.+)/,"<div>$1</div>");
```

Please note that this isn't the best approach when you're trying to modify HTML that consists of more complicated structures than a single text node, but it will do for this specific case.

As Jack has pointed out, you don't need to use a capturing group here since the entire match is already available using `$&`.

```
string = string.replace(/type.+/,"<div>$&</div>");
```

Comment: I just added my code with yours included. It did not work as anticipated. THis is just a quick one-time thing for a single text node

Comment: @JCHASE11 Here's a [short example](http://jsfiddle.net/KnAKG/) where you can see this working. Debugging the rest of your code is beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: +1. Deleted my question; you don't need the memory capturing parentheses, instead you can use `$&` in the replacement string.

Comment: @Jack I'll edit that into my answer, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Is this really the *only* way you have available?

Asad has a good example of a regex, **however**, he also points out that your approach is not best practice.

Why can't you just have some structure?

```
var returnedData = { "type": "div", "text": "I like best practice" };
//Might need error checking in future
var newElement = document.createElement(returnedData.type);
newElement.innerHTML = returnedData.text;
$("#wod span").append(newElement);
```